# Configure CRANEBOARD U-boot to load kernel images into SDcard via NETWORK

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot

I've one craneboard.it has sdcard which has u-boot v2013.04.I want to load kernel images via Network(using ethernet interface) into SD card.
What steps i should take for do this.
Please help.

Comment: You need to do this as a two-step transfer.  Use `tftpboot` to transfer the file from host to memory.  Then use the mmc command to write to SDcard.  See http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2014-February/174562.html and the built-in `help mmc` command.

Comment: It should be noted that the "mmc" commands directly access the SD Card. The card is accessed raw and as such there is no notion of partitions or file systems. Keep that in mind.

Comment: There is only u-boot in my mmc card.in **tftpboot** it needs loadaddress.what should i write there.Because craneboad has only u-boot.Nothing else.Please provide full procedure.thanks.

Comment: How will U-Boot read the kernel image from the SDcard?  The output of the `printenv` command should have the answer; please add that output to your question.  The loadaddress in the `tftpboot` command can be almost any low memory address; use the start of physical memory.

Comment: loadaddress is memory address. Just make sure the address is not used i.e not part of relocated u-boot or any exception handler.

Comment: Even ping commad is also not giving aspected output.It shows **'Host is not alive'**.If ping works then its possible to transfer images via tftp.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.Actually there was problem related to enabling some MACRO.
Include MACRO related to NET and  CONFIG_MACH_DAVINCI_DA850_EVM in am3517.h file.